# Handling Shared Data

Tags: java, static, shared

To develop a fully functional application consisting of more than 4 classes, what is the right way of handling shared data? I have researched about Static Methods and variables and Utility classes. It's said that use of Static methods hinders the concept of Object Orientation concept. So, if anybody could help me on how to use shared data between classes without hindering Object Oriented concept, then I would be highly grateful.

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4419810/how-to-share-data-between-separate-classes-in-java

Comment: @Rakes this is a QA site and m hoping for a answer to my confusion that I stated above. The link u provided does not provide a clear solution anyway....

Answer (score 1):

There are two primary axes of "inheritance" in object-oriented languages like Java. "Implementation" inheritance is where the sub-class inherits the actual code implementation from the parent. "Interface" inheritance is where the "sub-class" adheres to the public interface of the "parent".

Alas, Java actually mixes the two notions together a bit... Java interfaces are nice and clean -- when you "implement" an interface, you are stipulating that your class adheres to the "contract" of the interface that you specified. Java class inheritance isn't so clean -- when you sub-class in Java you are getting both the code inheritance but you are also stipulating that your sub-class adheres to the "contract" of the interface of the parent class.

Abstract classes in Java are just like regular Java classes but with the added constraint that you cannot instantiate them directly. In terms of that added constraint, they are basically classes which don't actually implement all of the code specified by their "contract".

So, it's generally considered good OO practice to specify the "contract" which you want to adhere to via Java interfaces. Then use normal Java class inheritance primarily for code reuse purposes. Use abstract Java classes when you want to provide some standard base code but want/need to force the user's of your class to complete the implementation (i.e., you create a skeleton implementation and the sub-classes must flesh it out).